# git clone (using ssh) from dev.azure.com suddenly asks for password

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, fedora

I have run into an unusual problem that when running a git command against azure-devops, it asks for a password for no apparent reason. Let's say, I run

```
git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/oranization/project/repo
```

Then it will ask

```
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
```

It worked a few weeks ago. I am completely flabbergasted, and any help is appreciated. My ssh config is

```
Host azure
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_openshift_tst_rsa
  #IdentitiesOnly yes
  Hostname ssh.dev.azure.com
Host workid
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host personalid
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_own_bitbucket_rsa
Host devbox
  Hostname dev.bovaris.io
  User vagrant
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host minishift
  Hostname 10.128.64.4
  User datalake
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_minishift_azure_rsa
Host home 
  HostName jelmervanamen.nl
  User pi
Host homeServer
  HostName jelmervanamen.nl
  Port 2222
  User jelmer
  ProxyCommand ssh jelmer@home nc %h %p %r
Host babyPi
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  HostName babypi.local
  Port 22
  User pi
  ProxyCommand ssh pi@home nc %h %p %r
Host jelmer-nas
  HostName 192.168.2.25 
  #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User jelmer
  PreferredAuthentications password
  #ProxyCommand ssh pi@home nc %h %p %r
Host jelmer-nas-sftp
  HostName 192.168.2.25 
  Port 2222
  #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User jelmer
  PreferredAuthentications password
  ProxyCommand ssh pi@home nc %h %p %r
Host jelmer-nas-sftp-direct
  HostName 192.168.2.25 
  Port 2222
  #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User jelmer
  PreferredAuthentications password
Host *.crv4all.com
 User AmenJ
 HashKnownHosts no
```

And gitconfig

```
    [alias]
        squash-all = "!f(){ git reset $(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -m \"${1:-A new start}\");};f"
        delete-merged-branches = ! git branch --merged | egrep -v '(^\\*|master|develop)' | xargs git branch -d
    [user]
        name = Jelmer van Amen
        email = jelmervanamen@gmail.com
    [push]
        default = current
        followTags = true
    [pull]
        rebase = true
            default = current
    [core]
        autocrlf = input
    [filesystem "AdoptOpenJDK|1.8.0_232|/dev/mapper/luks-bdcfeb1c-efb2-4631-8e46-9b7c0fca1c57"]
        timestampResolution = 1001 microseconds
        minRacyThreshold = 0 nanoseconds
```

Answer (score 5):

First step to debug ssh issues: use the `ssh` command to see what happens

```
ssh -v git@ssh.dev.azure.com
# ssh has several levels of verbosity:
ssh -vvv git@ssh.dev.azure.com
```

To debug how git uses ssh:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone ...
```

Comment: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone ...` to debug ssh with git.

Answer (score 3):

Fedora 33 changes its crypto policies.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/jhxbdh/no_ssh_public_key_auth_after_upgrade_to_fedora_33/

Following suggestions, it worked again. #thatwasconfusing

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged at SO; links rot, answers disappear. Can you please copy the gist of the answer here?

Comment: Yes, this is because Azure DevOps currently doesn't support a secure SSH configuration.  I recommend a different platform.

Comment: `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=ssh-rsa`.
Add this to the .ssh/config entry for ssh.dev.azure.com and the key will be accepted.